# Cross product and determinant areas of a Parallelogram

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, solution-verification, area, cross-product

If $x$ and $y$ are two column matrices that make up $A$, a 3x2 matrix, prove that $||x \times y||$ equals $\sqrt{\det(A^TA)}$? How does one go about this proof?

Comment: Have you looked on YouTube? I haven't watched any of them, but there are numerous videos on this subject.

Comment: @rogerl I have but didn't seem to get me anywhere

Comment: http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~fjones/chap8.pdf

Comment: This follows from the [Cauchy Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula), but I think that might be a bit of "overkill".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by writing $A^TA$ (simple matrix multiplication):$$A^TA=\begin{pmatrix}x^2&x\cdot y\\x\cdot y&y^2\end{pmatrix}$$
You can use [Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity), written in 3D:
$$|x\times y|^2=|x|^2|y|^2-(x\cdot y)^2$$
Alternatively, write explicitly the cross product components, square them, and add together.